# Laravel BelongsToMany Relation "Call to undefined relationship"

Tags: php, laravel

I can't find the problem in this case and need some help with Laravel Many to Many Relationship:

```
lluminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException
Call to undefined relationship [registered_events] on model [App\User].
```

**Whenever I try to access the relation the above error shows, eventhough the relation seems correct. The inverse relation works fine.**

User Model

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function registered_events() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class, 'event_user', 'user_id', 'event_id' )->withPivot('id', 'status', 'eventmanager', 'created_at', 'updated_at');
    }
}
```

Event Model

```php
class Event extends Model
{
    public function registered_users() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'event_user', 'event_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('id', 'status', 'eventmanager', 'created_at', 'updated_at');
    }
}
```

EventAllocationController

```php
public function admin_event_overview()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        // Problem here ⬇️
        $eventmanagers = $user->with('registered_events')->get();
        
        
        return view('dashboard.admin.event_allocation.overview', compact('user','eventmanagers'));
        
    }
```

Comment: try User::with('registered_events')->find(auth()->user()->id);

Comment: To expand, `$user` contains a single user. `with` should be used on a query builder statement. You can also use `$user->load('registered_events');` for a single user.

Comment: @aynber solution better in your case instead of find separately